# Finding the differences in xml nodes

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

XML/XSLT Newbie here.
I have some sets of data that need to be compared.  The output needs to be a list of Previous Members of a Roster that are not in the current Roster. The Node contains both sets of elements and I need to cycle through and put the missing member into a csv file.
In the example below, Kerry Smith is listed a 'Previous_Members' but not 'Member', so she needs to be listed in the output.

This same structure will occur for multiple teams.  And there can be different #'s on Different Teams. (Team Smith may have 4 members, Team Jones may have 7 members, Team Jackson may have 10, etc.)  So the solution needs to be able to handle a variable number of elements.

This is a big stretch for me experience-wise, so any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<am:Team>
<am:First_Day>08/24/2012</am:First_Day>
<am:_Date>08/23/2012</am:_Date>
<am:Member am:Descriptor="Clare Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D4</am:ID>
</am:Member>
<am:Members am:Descriptor="Jack Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D3</am:ID>
</am:Members>
<am:Members am:Descriptor="Colin Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D2</am:ID>
</am:Members>
<am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Kerry Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D1</am:ID>
</am:Previous_Members>
<am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Colin Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D2</am:ID>
</am:Previous_Members>
<am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Jack Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D3</am:ID>
</am:Previous_Members>
<am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Clare Smith">
    <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D4</am:ID>
</am:Previous_Members>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/am:Previous_Members[not(am:ID=/*/am:Member/am:ID)]
```

This selects all previous team members whose ID isn't an ID of a current member.

Apply templates only to the elements selected by this XPath expression.

**Update**:

The XML document as provided contains both: `am:Member` and `am:Members` -- this is probably a typing error.

**Correcting the above , so that there are only `am:Members`, the XML document becomes**:

```
<am:Team xmlns:am="some:am">
    <am:First_Day>08/24/2012</am:First_Day>
    <am:_Date>08/23/2012</am:_Date>
    <am:Members am:Descriptor="Clare Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D4</am:ID>
    </am:Members>
    <am:Members am:Descriptor="Jack Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D3</am:ID>
    </am:Members>
    <am:Members am:Descriptor="Colin Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D2</am:ID>
    </am:Members>
    <am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Kerry Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D1</am:ID>
    </am:Previous_Members>
    <am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Colin Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D2</am:ID>
    </am:Previous_Members>
    <am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Jack Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D3</am:ID>
    </am:Previous_Members>
    <am:Previous_Members am:Descriptor="Clare Smith">
        <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D4</am:ID>
    </am:Previous_Members>
</am:Team>
```

**The XPath expression becomes**:

```
/*/am:Previous_Members[not(am:ID=/*/am:Members/am:ID)]
```

**And, for the convenience of the OP, here is a complete transformation** that copies exactly the wanted nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:am="some:am" exclude-result-prefixes="am">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="am:Team/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="am:Previous_Members[not(am:ID=/*/am:Members/am:ID)] ">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<am:Previous_Members xmlns:am="some:am" am:Descriptor="Kerry Smith">
   <am:ID am:type="Member_ID">4588-D1</am:ID>
</am:Previous_Members>
```

Comment: Dimitre, Thank you..
I apologize if this is too basic of a follow-up, but 
would the code that includes this into the output be

    <xls:value-of select="/*/am:Previous_Members[not(am:ID=/*/am:Member/am:ID)]"/>

Comment: @JoeFoley, No. Just have: `<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/am:Previous_Members[not(am:ID=/*/am:Member/am:ID)]
"/>` . And have a template matching `am:Previous_Members`, that produces the CSV line for that particular member.

Comment: I must be dense..
I've tried what I **think** should be done, but just not getting it. I seem to get all records, not just the difference

        <xsl:template match="/Report_Data/Team">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Previous_Members[not(ID=Member/ID)]"/> 
            <xsl:value-of select="Previous_Members/@Descriptor"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:template>         
        <xsl:template match="Previous_Members[not(ID=Member/ID)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="ID"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        </xsl:template>

    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @JoeFoley, I am at work -- will lokk into this 7-8 hours from now.

Comment: @JoeFoley, See the update to my answer -- your provided XML was incorrect and misleading -- I corrected it and also modified the XPath expression accordingly. Also showed a simple complete transformation, to serve you as a base for the real one.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for... thank you very much!  You were correct about the typo in the XML. I apologize if that added confusion.